# Implicit conversion, import required or not?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I write

```
object MyString {
  implicit def stringToMyString(s: String) = new MyString(s)    
}

class MyString(str: String) {
  def camelize = str.split("_").map(_.capitalize).mkString

  override def toString = str
}


object Parse {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = "active_record".camelize
    // ...
  }
}
```

in my program. This causes a compiling error. After I inserted

```
  import MyString.stringToMyString
```

Then it works.

From Odersky's *Programming in Scala* I got that implicit conversion in the companion object of the source or expected target types don't need to be imported.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> implicit conversion in the companion
>   object of the source or expected
>   target types don't need to be
>   imported.

True enough. Now, the method `camelize` is defined on the class `MyString`, and, indeed, there is an implicit conversion to `MyString` inside its object companion. However, there is nothing in the code telling the compiler that `MyString` is the *expected* target type.

If, instead, you wrote this:

```
val x = ("active_record": MyString).camelize
```

then it would work, because the compiler would know you *expect* `"active_record"` to be a `MyString`, making it look up the implicit conversion inside object `MyString`.

This might look a bit restrictive, but it actually works in a number of places. Say, for instance, you had:

```
class Fraction(num: Int, denom: Int) {
    ...
    def +(b: Fraction) = ...
    ...
}
```

And then you had a code like this:

```
val x: Fraction = ...
val y = x + 5
```

Now, `x` does have a `+` method, whose *expected type*  is `Fraction`. So the compiler would look, here, for an implicit conversion from `Int` to `Fraction` inside the object `Fraction` (and inside the object `Int`, if there was one, since that's the source type).

Answer (score 13):

In this situation you need the import because the compiler doesn't know where you pulled out the `camelize` method from. If the type is clear, it will compile without import:

```
object Parse {
  def foo(s: MyString) = s.camelize

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = foo("active_record")
    println(x.toString)
  }
}
```

See [Pimp my library pattern](http://scala.sygneca.com/patterns/pimp-my-library), based on [Martin's article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766):

> Note that it is not possible to put defs at the top level, so you can’t define an implicit conversion with global scope. The solution is to place the def inside an object, and then import it, i.e.

```
object Implicits {
    implicit def listExtensions[A](xs : List[A]) = new ListExtensions(xs)
}
```

> And then at the top of each source file, along with your other imports:

```
import Implicits._
```

Comment: IIRC you can put the import into the package object, making it at least a little bit "global" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Rational class example in Programming in Scala book, put an implicit method in its companion object:

```
object Rational {
  implicit def intToRational(num: Int) = 
    new Rational(num)
}
```

but the code

```
2 + new Rational(1, 2)
```

does not work. For the conversion to happen, the single identifier rule applies, i.e., you need to import the explicit method into scope even though it is defined in the companion object.